# PHP DOMDocument: replace and wrap element

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

i have a html document, eg.:

```
<html>
<img src="/path-to-img/foo1.jpg">
<p>some other things</p>
<img src="/path-to-img/foo2.jpg">
</html>
```

now, i want replace all image with a new image and wrap the old in a `noscript` tag, eg.:

```
<html>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="/path-to-img/foo1.jpg">
<noscript><img src="/path-to-img/foo1.jpg"></noscript>
<p>some other things</p>
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" data-src="/path-to-img/foo2.jpg">
<noscript><img src="/path-to-img/foo2.jpg"></noscript>
</html>
```

it seems simple :) but not for me!

I have tried this:

```
<?php
function callback($htmlBuffer) {

    $doc = new DomDocument();
    $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = true;

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($htmlBuffer);
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    // search all image
    $images = $doc->getElementsByTagName('img');

    foreach ($images as $image) {

        $src = $image->getAttribute('src');

        /** @var $parent DOMElement */
        $parent = $image->parentNode;

        // clone the old image in a new image
        $newDoc   = new DOMDocument();
        $newImage = $newDoc->importNode($image, true);

        $newImage->setAttribute('src', 'data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7');
        $newImage->setAttribute('data-src', $src);
        $parent->appendChild($newImage); // Exception here!!!!

        // wrap the old image with a noscript tag
        $noscript = $doc->createElement('noscript');
        $parent->replaceChild($noscript, $image);
        $noscript->apendChild($image);
    }

    return $doc->saveHTML();
}
```

see online [DEMO](http://codepad.org/Tjr5y9jF)

the script raise a exceprion

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'DOMException' with message 'Wrong Document Error'

I do not understand how to use DOMDocument

Comment: Are you trying to replace the DOM content *after* the page has loaded? Wouldn't an AJAX method be better?

Comment: @Jay is important replace the DOM before the page has loaded

Comment: you can use Jquery here:
<html>
<img src="/path-to-img/foo1.jpg" />
<p>some other things</p>
<img src="/path-to-img/foo2.jpg" />
</html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(function(){
  $("img").each(function(){
   var src = $(this).attr('src');
   $(this).attr({
    'src' : "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7", 
    'data-src' : src
   });
   $(this).after( "<noscript><img src="+src+"></noscript>" );
  })
 })
</script>

Comment: I need a php solution